# mvn -version command running in the home directory but not anywhere else

Tags: maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juHcC.png)I have added the M2_HOME variable and have added it to path in my .bash_profile. "mvn -version" command is successfully running at my home location but not where I actually want to run the man command(inside a directory).

What m I missing here?

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: First please download a more recent version of Maven ...second do not use M2_HOME only put the bin directory of the unzipped distro in your path variable....

Comment: Useful information to add:  * location of mvn (try 'whereis mvn' to get that info)  * contents of PATH (try 'echo $PATH')  * output of running it from a different directory